# Android Load Media from All Folders

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I just learn Android programming for several months. I tried to create simple music player, but I got problem when I want to open all mp3 files, since I only can open 1 spesific folder, eg "sdcard".

I found this sample code from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/#) to play mp3 file from "sdcard" only.

```
public class SongsManager {
// SDCard Path
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Constructor
public SongsManager(){

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
 * and store the details in ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

/**
 * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
 * */
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
```

While I found another code that can read all mp3 files from whole sdcard with recursive, but I got confused since I don't get how to call the functions into code above.

This is the code :

```
    // this method creates a list of file extensions that will be searched
//
public static ArrayList<String> createAudioExtensionsList()
{
    ArrayList<String> extensions = new ArrayList<String>();

    extensions.add(".mp3");
    extensions.add(".ogg");
    extensions.add(".flac");
    extensions.add(".wav");
    extensions.add(".3gp");

    return extensions;
}

// simple method to get a file extension (does not work with complex extensions like .tar.gz)
//
public static String getFileExtension(String fileName)
{ 
    String result = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")); 
    return result;
}

// recursively scans a folder for all files containing one of the file extensions
//
public static LinkedList<File> getFilesInFolder(File rootDir, ArrayList<String> extensions)
{
    LinkedList<File> results = new LinkedList<File>();
    File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();

    for(File file : files)
    {
        if(file.isDirectory())
            results.addAll(getFilesInFolder(file, extensions));
        else
        {
            for(String s : extensions)
            {
                String ext = getFileExtension(file.getName());
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(ext))
                    results.add(file);
            }
        }
    }   
    return results;
}
```

I believe that **getFileExtension** will return all data of mp3 songs, but I don't understand how to call it into main functions (**File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);**). I hope you can help or tell me how exactly we can call the functions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to disappoint but all this code to manually search for files is already done automatically by the [Content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) all you have to do is to query the content provider for music.

The [Media Store](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) holds the references to the fields you want to query for.

Probably something like this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                           MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                           MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                           MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                           MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME }, "1=1", null, null);
```

and then you have a cursor with the music id, a stream to the actual music, the artist name, album name and display name,

Comment: Is it possible to only catch only path of the mp3 files?

Comment: I know for photos you can, so probably yes. But you'll have to Google a bit about the MediaStore and the content provider to find cause I don't know it by heart!

Answer (score 2):

**To get the all songs**

```
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    musicPath = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    musicTitle= new String[cursor.getCount()];
    count=cursor.getCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do{
        musicPath[cursor.getPosition()]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        musicTitle[cursor.getPosition()]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1,musicTitle);
    MusicList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    cursor.close();
```

**Implement musiclist onclick listner**. In that listener u will get the **position** of clicked song , so pass the **path of that song** to next activity via intent . and play it as follows.

To play the song , select it from list and start new aactivity and play it as follows

```
Mediaplayer mp =new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSoruce(getIntent().getStringExtra("Path","NULL"));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```